# Solution to a slope field through given points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, computational-mathematics, boundary-value-problem

I want to find solutions to a slope field given certain initial conditions. Say I have a slope field of the form:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \cos(z)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin(z)$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = f(x,y,z)$$
Given $x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1$, I want to find $z_0, z_1$ such that there is a solution to the slope field passing through $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$. What methods exist to solve problems of this sort? My end goal is to solve problems of this sort numerically with both consistency and speed on a computer, but theoretical insight is useful too.

Comment: Begin by a bit of numerical plotting with different expressions for $f$.It will help you to formulate conjectures.

Comment: I think we should assume there's no good closed form for the solution and focus on computational methods.